# In MongoDB, do document _id's need to be unique across a collection or the entire DB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm building a database with several collections. I have unique strings that I plan on using for all the documents in the main collection. Documents in other collections will reference documents in the main collection, which means I'll have to save said id's in the other collections. However, if _id's only need to be unique across a collection and not across an entire database, then I would just make the _id's in the other collections also use the aforementioned unique strings.

Also, I assume that in order to set my own _id's, all I have to do is have an `"_id":"unique_string"` property as part of the document that I insert, correct? I wouldn't need to convert the "unique_string" into another format, right?

Also, hypothetically speaking, would I be able to have a variable save the string "_id" and use that instead? Just to be clear, something as follows: `var id = "_id"` and then later on in the code (during an insert or a query for example) have `id:"unique_string"`.

Best, and thanks,
Sami

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`_id`s have to be unique in a collection. You can quickly verify this by inserting two documents with the same `_id` in two different collections.

Your other assumptions are correct, just try them and see whether they work (they will). The proof of the pudding is in the eating.

Note: use `_id` directly, `var id = "_id"` just compilcates the code.

Comment: thanks! I guess you're right - I could have easily just tried this out myself. also, the id = "_id" question was meant more for other potential keys in a given document, rather than "_id" itself. if it works for one, it'll work for others. thanks for your response though! i appreciate it!

Comment: hey yi_H, I just wanted to let you know that the latter part of your answer is incorrect. You cannot use variables to represent keys - at least not directly. you'd have to save a document beforehand and pass that document into the query if you wanted to do anything with variables along those lines.

Comment: @thisissami: I don't understand you... I can think of a couple of reasons why it doesn't work, e.g.: in a javascript object literal the key part is parsed as a string (that's why you never have to quote it). You can do it with `id="_id"; doc = {...}; doc[id] = value;`

Comment: do embedded documents need to have unique _id in a collection or they can be duplicate?